# Google location search custom dataset

Tags: google-maps-api-3, search-engine

I have a data set of locations and would like to allow users to search with advanced things like Search for X near Y.

I have the ability for handling X using all of the meta data about my locations but I don't have the ability to return a result if they type

find X near I35
or
find X near Starbucks

Does anyone know of a way to get this sort of functionality, commercial or free.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Google Fusion Tables SQL API:

http://code.google.com/apis/fusiontables/

This gives you an SQL-like interface for doing both "X has property Y" and "X is near Y"

It also lets you display these results on a Google Map very easily.